# ios Facebook Login showing "Invalid Scope: basic_info". use public_profile, user_friends instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want app should works in all three condition.
I'm using following code in my viewdidload method and implemented delegate method.

```
FBLoginView *fb_loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
fb_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_friends"];
fb_loginView.delegate = self;
fb_loginView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 300, 100);
[self.view addSubview:fb_loginView];
```

Case-I working fine But 
Case-II & Case-III not working

**Case-I :** (FB app is not installed on device & only FB credentials is stored in settings)
          In this case when I pressed on login button its ask me permissions and I can fetched users basic info.

**Case-II** : (FB app is installed But FB credentials is not stored in settings)
          In this case when I pressed on login button its takes me to FB installed for login. I logged in, but showing error 
**"Invalid Scope: basic_info". use public_profile, user_friends instead.**

**Case-III :** (FB app is not installed and FB credentials is not stored in settings)
          In this case when I pressed on login button its takes me to ios safari browser for fb login. I logged in, but showing same error 
**"Invalid Scope: basic_info". use public_profile, user_friends instead.**

**When I used**

```
fb_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

**Then** Case-I & Case-II works fine but Case-III showing following error.

> Error = Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1cd61ba0
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The
>   proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being
>   installed previously." UserInfo=0x1cd622e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app
>   cannot request publish permissions without having being installed
>   previously.}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
>   0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you how to fix it.

`@"basic_info"` is no longer accepted by the Facebook API. You should be using `@"public_profile"` or `@"user_friends"`, or `@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]` instead (depending on your use case).

The error that you are seeing when you have used `@"public_profile"` is not related to this Facebook request. It is related to a request where you have requested `@"publish_actions"`, hence the message "The proxied app cannot request **publish** permissions without having being installed previously."